# How to take a few lines of numerical data from text document in Python, do an operation with them and write it out in text document?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 sets of numerical data in lines and columns saved in 2 text documents. I want to take first 20 lines from each document merge it together and put it into a third document. Also I want this to repeat for every 20 lines until the end of the original documents. I'm using numpy and scipy.

I'm using numpy and scipy. I tried using islice, as I found this in other question, but it just prints out the data.

My data sets look like this:

```
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.00000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.01200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.02400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.03600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.04800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.06000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.07200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.08400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.09600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.10800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.12000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.13200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.14400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.15600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.16800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.18000000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.19200000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.20400000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.21600000 0.7187500000000000 
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.22800000 0.7187500000000000 
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.24000000 0.7187500000000000 
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.00000000 0.8750000000000000
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.01200000 0.8750000000000000 
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.02400000 0.8750000000000000
...
```

The second column shows the ordinal number of the 20 lines which I want to use, merge with data from the other document and write in third document. The ordinal number goes until 100 - it could maybe be helpful to use this number in a loop, but I haven't figured it how.

Comment: As soon as you have the contents of the file, perhaps you could go through each line and split each line at whitespace using .split(); the result should contain the number in the second column at index [1].

Comment: it looks like tabed data which are similar to csv file (but use tab instead of comma) and you can read it with module `csv` or even `pandas` (`read_csv()`)  or numpy.

Comment: show your code and full error message (if you have it).

Comment: Welcome to SO vu_ra. I suggest you read the help on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. If you have some code, please add it to your question and, as furas asked, include any error messages.

Comment: if you  only need to read lines and write them in another file then you can use loop with standard `open()`, readline()` and `write()`. It seems that every line has always the same length then you can treat it as normal text and use slicing `[star:end]` to get substring with number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard `open()`, `readline()` and `write()` to copy lines from one file to another.

Instead of two `readline()` I using `zip()` you can get lines from both files.

Because I'm don't know how many spaces can be between columns so I use `re.split()` instead of normal `split()`

I use second column to create name of output file. I also do it for every line to make it simpler - but it can be slower to open and close file in every loop.

```
import re

# open input files    
input_file_1 = open('filename_1')
input_file_2 = open('filename_2')

for line_1, line_2 in zip(input_file_1, input_file_2):
    # remove '\n` at the end
    line_1 = line_1.strip()
    line_2 = line_2.strip()

    # create one line to write
    line = line_1 + ' ' + line_2 + '\n'

    # get second column to create filename
    column_2 = re.split('\s+', line_1)[1]
    #print(column_2)

    # open output file, append new line and close it
    output_file = open('output'+column_2, 'a')
    output_file.write(line)
    output_file.close()

# close input files
input_file_1.close()
input_file_2.close()
```

---

Example using `io.StringIO` instead of real file - so everyone can copy it and run it to test it.

```
data1 = '''128  1   0.350   5.175   0.00000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.01200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.02400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.03600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.04800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.06000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.07200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.08400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.09600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.10800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.12000000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.13200000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.14400000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.15600000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.16800000 0.3750000000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.18000000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.19200000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.20400000 0.7187500000000000
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.21600000 0.7187500000000000 
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.22800000 0.7187500000000000 
128  1   0.350   5.175   0.24000000 0.7187500000000000 
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.00000000 0.8750000000000000
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.01200000 0.8750000000000000 
128  2   0.350   5.175   0.02400000 0.8750000000000000'''

import io

input_file_1 = io.StringIO(data1)
input_file_2 = io.StringIO(data1)

import re

#input_file_1 = open('filename_1')
#input_file_2 = open('filename_2')

for line_1, line_2 in zip(input_file_1, input_file_2):
    line_1 = line_1.strip()
    line_2 = line_2.strip()
    line = line_1 + ' ' + line_2 + '\n'

    column_2 = re.split('\s+', line_1)[1]
    print(column_2)

    output_file = open('output'+column_2, 'a')
    output_file.write(line)
    output_file.close()

input_file_1.close()
input_file_2.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants the data combined in this way (zipping columns), but I could be wrong. The other problem with `zip` is that it will drop data if there are not exactly the same number of lines in each input. Again, this might not be a problem if vu_ra confirms the files will _always_ contain 20 rows of each index group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say "merge it together" you want all the lines with the same index grouped together. Not merged in the way furas has by using `zip`.

It's also not clear if you want each set of grouped indexes in separate files or all the results in one file. My solution writes all the lines from the input files in to a single file, but it would not be difficult to separate them.

Rather than trying to read the data and combine it at the same time, I've chosen to read all the data and sort it in memory. You say the files contain 20 rows for each group, and the groups can go up to 100, so you have a small data set which is easily handled in memory.

The code will look for any `.txt` files in the input path, load the lines as arrays and then sort the arrays on the second element. Finally all the rows are converted back to tab delimited strings and written to the file.

This solution will also handle any number of input files by using `os.walk` and still work in situations where there are incomplete sets; e.g. there are not 20 rows of index 2

```
import os
import re

input_path = './input/'
combined = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            with open(os.path.join(input_path, file), 'r') as input_file:
                for line in input_file:
                    combined.append(re.split('\s+', line.strip()))

combined.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as output_file:
    for line in combined:
        output_file.write("\t".join(line)+'\n')
```